# Call API via uri module in Ansible

Tags: api, ansible, uri

While calling the api `<towername>/api/v2/job_templates/<templ_name>/launch` via uri module on the localhost, I am getting error as

> Status code was 500 and not [201]: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error

I am passing the below attributes in the playbook:
method, validate_certs,status_code, return_content, body_format,user, password,   force_basic_auth.

Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Body attribute was missing, once I updated, it worked fine.